# How to retrieve a data from a custom table to JSON?

Tags: json

I'm trying to retrieve the data from the database and return it to JSON so that I can access the data in jquery...

thanks!

Comment: Hey Joel, the answers to that question I posted should explain how to do what you want.

Comment: Hi carlcs,  thanks for the reply... How can i display this data? for example   [1147651200000,67.79],
[1147737600000,64.98],
[1147824000000,65.26],
[1147910400000,63.18],
[1147996800000,64.51],
[1148256000000,63.38],
[1148342400000,63.15],
[1148428800000,63.34],
[1148515200000,64.33],
[1148601600000,63.55],
[1148947200000,61.22],
[1149033600000,59.77],
/* Jun 2006 */
[1149120000000,62.17],
[1149206400000,61.66],
[1149465600000,60.00],
[1149552000000,59.72],
[1149638400000,58.56],
[1149724800000,60.76],
[1149811200000,59.24],
[1150070400000,57.00],
[1150156800000,58.33]